# ERROR in ./node_modules/httpntlm/ntlm.js - Module parse failed: Identifier directly after number (427:47)

Tags: node.js, typescript

hi this is my first time asking question on SO and hoping someone could help me. I'm trying to use httpntlm module and while I'm trying to use this code:
const httpntlm = require('httpntlm')
I'm getting error

`

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/httpntlm/ntlm.js
Module parse failed: Identifier directly after number (427:47)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|       // 11644473600000 = diff between 1970 and 1601
|       var now = Date.now();
|       var timestamp = ((BigInt(now) + 11644473600000n) * 10000n);
|       var timestampBuffer = Buffer.alloc(8);
|       timestampBuffer.writeBigUInt64LE(timestamp);
 @ ./node_modules/httpntlm/httpntlm.js 13:11-28
 @ ./src/services/createViewingSession.service.ts
 @ ./src/services/index.ts
 @ ./src/index.ts
```

`

I really appreciate your help. Thank you.

I tried to use other version of nvm (15.5.1) and (16.10.0) to create package using this command "npm run package" but no luck.

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.